# Изменить this в методе класса с++

Tags: c++, классы, конструктор, this, оператор-присваивания

Ситуация такова, внутри метода класса List удаляю объект, с которым работаю, а после этого хочу запустить конструктор копирования для этого же объекта, но получается так что этот объект не меняется, подскажите в чем ошибка и как решить вопрос.
Код метода:

```
 List& List::operator=(List& first_list) {
        if (&first_list == this) return (*this);
        n = first_list.n;
        this->~List();
        List::List(first_list);
        return *this; // Не меняется после конструктора копирования, который применяется выше
    }
```

Comment: `this->~List();` - Вы кoгда-нибудь пробовали выдернуть ковер у себя из-под ног? Попробуйте. Вот это что должно делать? - `List::List(first_list);`

Comment: Вы творите какую то дичь... Остановитесь и подумайте что вам нужно, то что у вас написано это просто бред

Comment: [Шепотом, восхищенно] Это ж надо до такого додуматься! Это ж почище стрельбы в ногу... Да, скажите, а вы не пробовали заодно путем вызова `int(5)` превратить свой `List` в `int`? Должно работать с тем же успехом, что и `List::List(first_list);`...

Comment: @Igor если не трогать после этого члены, то ничего страшного в удалении объекта нет, ведь функции-члены никуда не деваются. Так сказать на ковер можно и не наступать после его удаления.

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan - формально, это все равно неопределенное поведение - обращение к несуществующему объекту. Компилятор имеет полное право устроить забастовку.

Comment: @gbg как минимум ведущие собаководы говорят что [ок](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#delete-this)

Comment: `n = first_list.n; this->~List();` - вы меняете `n` и вызываете деструктор. Скорее всего здесь будет крушение или утечка памяти.

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan Там написан ряд условий, например, что нельзя после удаления обращаться ни к полям, ни к методам. *this после delete this - это именно что попытка разыменовать указатель, который уже никуда не ведет.

Comment: @gdg так я и написал "если не трогать после этого члены"

Answer (score 3):

Если уж вы хотите написать оператор присваивания через копирующий конструктор - да, это возможно. Но тут идиома иная.

Пишется функция `swap`, которая меняет местами "внутренности" вашего класса с другим. Типа, если есть

```
class CLASS {
private:
    type1 t1;
    type2 t2;
    ...

swap(CLASS& c) { std::swap(t1,c.t1); std::swap(t2,c.t2); ... }
```

Ну, а после этого все присваивание сводится к

```
CLASS& operator=(const CLASS& c)
{
    CLASS tmp(c);
    swap(tmp);
    return *this;
}
```

Можно даже не писать проверку на присваивание класса самому себе - сработает. Разве что написать ее для эффективности :)

Вот как выглядит эта идиома.